# HTTP status code to indicate that proxy doesn't support CONNECT

Tags: http, status, http-proxy

How should an HTTP proxy, when receiving a CONNECT request from the client, indicate that the proxy does not support CONNECT?  I tried to read [RFC2817](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2817), but didn't find any information about the case when CONNECT is not supported.

Answer (score 4):

## HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed

`CONNECT`, despite its distinct behavior, is still a request method, and according to [RFC 2616 section 10.4.6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.4.6) (`CONNECT` was originally specified as a reserved verb in RFC2616), HTTP 405 should be used when:

```
The method specified in the Request-Line is not allowed for the
resource identified by the Request-URI. The response MUST include an
Allow header containing a list of valid methods for the requested
resource.
```

RFCs [7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230) and [7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.6) which updates and obsoletes both the original HTTP/1.1 specification as well as RFC2817 makes no mention of recommended responses to indicate CONNECT as not supported, in which case I assume the above still to be a valid interpretation

Comment: This seems to make sense, but I wonder how the cache would then know what to put into the "Allow" header (which MUST be included according to the above sniplet)?